# How to select any item preceded by some word in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I need to do is really simple (Theoretically). I have a some selectors like these:

```
.foo-one{
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.foo-two{
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

What I need to do is to select any item that start with ".foo-" to apply a global style to all of them, because I don't want to do something like:

```
.foo-one{
    transition: border 1s linear;
}

.foo-two{
    transition: border 1s linear;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you can't add another class? That would be simpler, I think...

Comment: The simplest way is to use attribute selectors, but if you can show us your markup we can find a better-tailored solution.

Comment: I'm suggest to check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to get familiar with `CSS`selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap used selector like this `[class^="foo-"]`

`^="string"` means start with `string`

[CSS3 Attribute Selectors](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[class|=foo]
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7X4X/

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[class*="foo-"]{ 
    .. styles for all classes starting with foo- ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If theres going to be a lot of different classes starting with `foo`, I would recommend creating an extra class for this called `foo` for example, so you can just do:

```
.foo{
    transition: border 1s linear;
}
```

However if this is not an option, rather than 2 styles, you could have 1 using 2 selectors in your rule:

```
.foo-one,
.foo-two{
    transition: border 1s linear;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend trying to create one selector to suit different class names starting with `foo`. It defeats the point of class names.

Answer (score 0):

By searching a bit, I found this, that's not exactly what you wanted, but that could do it:

```
.foo-one,.foo-two {
    transition: border 1s linear;
}
```

Source: "http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp"